# What is the proper way to include partial in liquid templates in eleventy 1?

Tags: liquid, eleventy

Given the following file structure:

```
root/
  src/
    _includes/
      partials/
        navbar.liquid
        footer.liquid
        address.liquid
      base.liquid
    index.liquid
```

How do I include *partials/navbar.liquid* and *partials/footer.liquid* in *base.liquid* and include *partials/address.liquid* in *partials/footer.liquid* ?

**NOTE:** This behavior has changed in version 1 and I cannot figure out the new model. A working solution would be a great addition to the 11ty documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project structure looks good. I created a small [demo repo](https://github.com/tannerdolby/liquid-11ty-demo) with v1.0.1 and the [`{% include %}`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/template/#include) logic works as expected with liquid templates when the correct template filepaths are provided.

*src/_includes/base.liquid*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>11ty demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include "./partials/navbar.liquid" %}
    {{ content }}
    {% include "./partials/footer.liquid" %}
</body>
</html>
```

*src/index.liquid*

```
---
layout: base.liquid
pageTitle: 11ty demo
---

<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
<p>Some content</p>
```

#### Partials

*src/_includes/partials/navbar.liquid*

```
<nav><a href="/">Home Page Link</a></nav>
```

*src/_includes/partials/address.liquid*

```
<p>221 Some address info</p>
```

*src/_includes/partials/footer.liquid*

```
{% include "./address.liquid" %}
<nav><a href="/">Footer link</a></nav>
```

After performing a build with `npx @11ty/eleventy` and then serving the site with `npx @11ty/eleventy --serve`. Below is the generated site output:

[image: Screenshot of 11ty site output for demo code]